# Using SSIS to separate long text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

Example of input:

> column 1 column 2 column 3 column 4 column 5
>
> EE12   2014-05-17 22:05:36.260  2  3 
>   12345678901234567890123456789123456789457908

How the output should look like:

> column 1 column 2 column 3 column 4 column 5
>
> EE12   2014-05-17 22:05:36.260  2  3  1234
>
> EE12   2014-05-17 22:05:36.260  2  3  5678

For column 5 which is the long text, I need to separate the long text into 4 characters each. The longest data length is 10800. For columns 1 to 4 will be remain the same. Every 4 characters, there will be a new row recorded.

I am using SSIS script component to do this. I need help in the C# coding to separate the long text and write into database.

THe method i use to spilt the characters into 4 characters each

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        //Regax method to seperated the text into 4 characters each
        var input = Row.value.ToString();       
        var regex = new Regex(@".{4}");
        string result = regex.Replace(input, "$&" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

}
```

Comment: @MJH i tried to use derived column and  conditional split. However, it can't works.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and explain _how_ is is not working. Otherwise I doubt you will receive many helpful responses.

Comment: Use _asynchronous script component_, you'll be able to read in each row and manipulate the output according to what you need.

[Link to reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx)

Comment: One basic question.... The data which you are trying to work upon is in database or DataTable in C#? If it is in DataBase, you can fetch only 4 characters and work upon it. But if it is in C#, there are many options available. Please clarify what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //prepare for  splitting the long text and writing into database
            string originalData = "EE12 2014-05-17 22:05:36.260 2 3 1234567890123456789012345678912345678945790842";
            string [] constantField = originalData.Split(' ');
            //previous line results as follow:
            //[0] EE12
            //[1] 2014-05-17
            //[2] 22:05:36.260
            //[3] 2
            //[4] 3
            //[5] 1234567890123456789012345678912345678945790842
            StringBuilder splitingCharacters = new StringBuilder(constantField[5]);
            splitingCharacters.Append(constantField[5]);
           // splitting and writing
           SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[4];
            sqlParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@column1",SqlDbType.Char,constantField[0].Length);
            sqlParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@column2", SqlDbType.Char, constantField[1].Length + constantField[2].Length+1);
            sqlParams[2] = new SqlParameter("@column3", SqlDbType.Char, constantField[3].Length);
            sqlParams[3] = new SqlParameter("@column4", SqlDbType.Char, constantField[4].Length);

            sqlParams[0].Value = constantField[0];
            sqlParams[1].Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", constantField[1], constantField[2]);
            sqlParams[2].Value = constantField[3];
            sqlParams[3].Value = constantField[4];

            while (splitingCharacters.Length > 0)
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("your connection sql "))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("insert into table1 (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) values (@column1,@column2,@column3,@column4,@column5)", sqlConn);
                    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
                    //Spliting the text from left to right.
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column5",SqlDbType.Char,4).Value = splitingCharacters.ToString(0, 4));
                    splitingCharacters.Remove(0, 4);
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    int result = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up **Asynchronous Script Component**, than you should be able to write something like the sample below. I did not test the code below, do comment if there are any issues with it.

Use this as a guide to get you started.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var column1Value = Row.Column1;
    var column2Value = Row.Column2;
    var column3Value = Row.Column3;
    var column4Value = Row.Column4;
    var column5Value = Row.Column5;

    while(column5Value.Length > 0)
    {
        var rowData = "";
        if (column5Value.Length > 4)
        {
            rowData = column5Value.Substring(0, 4);
            column5Value = column5Value.Substring(4);
        }
        else
        {
            rowData = column5Value;
            column5Value = "";
        }

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.Column1 = column1Value;
        Output0Buffer.Column2 = column2Value;
        Output0Buffer.Column3 = column3Value;
        Output0Buffer.Column4 = column4Value;
        Output0Buffer.Column5 = rowData;            
    }
}
```